# What does mean of the rule ? scripts/Kbuild.include: ;

Tags: makefile

There are a rule in the uboot top makefile.  the rule is "scripts/Kbuild.include: ;". I want to know Why write this code.What is its function.

```
 I want to learn the uboot top makefile.
```

Comment: It tells Make that there is no need to do anything to rebuild `scripts/Kbuild.include`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.